# Gratis Android application that can remove the cache of all my Android applications at once

Tags: gratis, android, caching, cleaner

I'm looking for a gratis Android application that can remove the cache of all my Android applications at once.

[CCleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piriform.ccleaner&hl=en_US&gl=US) doesn't do it for free:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm probably mistaken, but I thought they changed Android so one app can't delete the cache of another app programmatically (even with user consent).  I'm guessing, though, it could still be done in a roundabout way like this app freezes other apps: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/superfreeze.tool.android/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go this way, you could try [1Tap Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.free&hl=en_IN&gl=US)

(However, honestly I'm not convinced you really want to delete hidden cache. For most apps it's hidden for a reason. Could well be you'll experience some issues afterwards - been there done that.)